# Is there a quick way to get the R equivalent of ls() in Python?

Tags: python, r

I'm new to Python and normally use R, and regularly use `ls()` to get a vector of all the objects in my current environment, is there something that does the same thing quickly in Python?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

This may not be entirely obvious at first, but when you're at global scope (as you usually are at the command-line interpreter), the "current local scope" is the global scope (in this case, of the `__main__` module). So, this will return all the variables and functions you've defined, all the modules you've imported, and a few things that get attached to every module or just to `__main__`. For example:

```
$ python3.3
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> import sys
>>> i = 2+3
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', 'i', 'sys']
```

This is always the same thing as `sorted(locals().keys())`, but `dir()` is a lot easier to type. And of course it's nicely parallel with `dir(sys)` to get the things defined by the `sys` module, `dir(i)` to get the attributes of that integer object `5`, etc.

Comment: nice ... I had no idea what he was talking about :P