# Equivalent of R's ls() function in Python to remove all created objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python. There is a function in R called `ls()`. I can easily remove any created objects using `ls()` and `rm()` functions as bellow.

**R Code**

```
# Create x and y
x = 1
y = "a"

# remove all created objects
ls()
# [1] "x" "y"
rm(list = ls())

# Try to print x
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669375/is-there-a-quick-way-to-get-the-r-equivalent-of-ls-in-python) post someone suggested an equivalent of `ls()` in python. So, I have tried to do the same operation in python.

**Python Code**

```
# Create x and y
x = 1
y = "a"

# remove all created objects
for v in dir(): del globals()[v]

# Try to print x
x
# NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

But the problem is when `x` is recreated and printed it is throwing error:

```
# Recreate x
x = 1

# Try to print x
x
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       x
>
> File
>   "C:\SomePath\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.py",
>   line 258, in **call**
>       self.update_user_ns(result)
>
> File
>   "C:\SomePath\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.py",
>   line 196, in update_user_ns
>       if result is not self.shell.user_ns['_oh']:
>
> KeyError: '_oh'

I have noticed `dir()` give some extra objects other than my objects. Is there any function which will give the same output like R's `ls()`?

Comment: why not just `del x`? you don't need to delete everything in `globals()`, this is asking for trouble! (BTW can't reproduce in the python interactive mode, guess this is something related to your setup)

Comment: If this is about IPython specifically, you can always restart your kernel with `Ctrl+.` to be in a fresh new environment.

Comment: or perhaps. `for v in dir(): if not v.startswith('_'): del globals()[v]` to keep private stuff

Comment: What if I have too many objects to delete? @Chris_Rands

Comment: See my 2nd comment, but this is a pretty odd thing to want to do, why do you need to clear the namespace like this?

Comment: I might have a object like __MyObject__ (Start with underscore, not showing in the comment). Then? @Chris_Rands

Comment: The below SO link has the answer.. Please have a look. It seems similar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549854/equivalent-of-r-ls-but-only-for-user-generated-objects-functions

Comment: Thanks @Arihant That was the closest solution of my problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why can't you just start a new interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different questions here.

> Is this code correct?

```
# remove all created objects
for v in dir(): del globals()[v]
```

No it is not! First `dir()` returns the keys from the local mapping. At module level, it is the same as `globals()`, but not inside a function. Next it contains some objects that you do not want to remove like `__builtins__`...

> Is there any function which will give the same output like R's ls()?

Not exactly, but you can try to mimic it with a class:

```
class Cleaner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
    def reset(self):
        self.keep = set(globals());
    def clean(self):
        g = list(globals())
        for __i in g:
            if __i not in self.keep:
                # print("Removing", __i)      # uncomment for tracing what happens
                del globals()[__i]
```

When you create a cleaner object, it keeps a list (more exactly a `set` object) of all pre-existing objects. When you call its `clean` method, it removes from its `globals()` mapping all objects that were added since its creation (including itself!)

Example (with uncommented tracing):

```
>>> class Cleaner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
    def reset(self):
        self.keep = set(globals());
    def clean(self):
        g = list(globals())
        for __i in g:
            if __i not in self.keep:
                print("Removing", __i)      # uncomment for tracing what happens
                del globals()[__i]


>>> dir()
['Cleaner', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
>>> c = Cleaner()
>>> i = 1 + 2
>>> import sys
>>> dir()
['Cleaner', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'c', 'i', 'sys']
>>> c.clean()
Removing c
Removing i
Removing sys
>>> dir()
['Cleaner', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

Answer (score 3):

Coming from R, the most satisfactory solution I've found is to simply restart the kernel. The downside is that you lose all your *imports*, but I've learned to live with that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27069549)

Comment: Okay: "just restart the kernel".  That answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Base on @Arihant's comment I have tried:

```
zzz = %who_ls
for v in zzz : del globals()[v]
del v,zzz
```

I hope this could be done in a single line. Any suggestions are welcome.

Another similar solution is:

```
%reset -f
```